# How to disable pdfmarkupcomment?

Tags: pdf, comments, pdfcomment, markup

I filled my thesis with lot of pdfmarkupcomments which come as a part of  the package pdfcomment. Is there a way to disable this comments globally. Or should I go manually to every place I made it and disable them?

Answer (score 6):

Use the package option `final` as explained on page 4 of the documentation.